# Difference between Spring and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

There are many people who advised me to use Spring Boot instead of Spring to develop REST web services.
I want to know what exactly the difference between the two is?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In short

1. Spring Boot reduces the need to write a lot of configuration and boilerplate code.
2. It has an opinionated view on Spring Platform and third-party libraries so you can get started with minimum effort.
3. Easy to create standalone applications with embedded Tomcat/Jetty/Undertow.
4. Provides metrics, health checks, and externalized configuration.

You can read more here http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: Would like a definition of _opinionated_ ... is it opinionated based on the use case...so if I use it for developing a RESTful webservice, is that opinionated slant, to do with getting the boiler-plating and 3rd part libs to get a RESTful webservice done? it would be really nice to know...

Comment: I would love myself to fully understand the concept of "opinionated view". I can see very well that it is phrase it that way on the Spring Boot website: https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/, but still it would be good to have an explanation of what this really means.

Comment: The definition of *opinionated - characterized by conceited assertiveness and dogmatism*. In simpler English, Spring Boot configures many properties about the RESTful service for you, although they could be configured differently. So they have an *opinion* about how things should be done and save you from a lot of extra effort. Honestly, in the end, you would probably do things the same way. But if you need to change very specific or low level properties, you still have the opportunity to do that in Spring Boot. Source: my imagination.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately and I mean this out of personal frustration with Spring boot, I have yet to see any real quantified list, where the differences are explicitly outlined.
There is only qualifications such as the rubbish sentence "...opinionated view..." which are bandied about.

What *is* clear, is that SpringBoot has wrapped up groups of Spring annotations into its own set of annotations, implicitly.
Further obfuscating, and making the need for anyone starting out in SpringBoot to have to commit to memory what a particular SpringBoot annotation represents.

My reply therefore is of no quantifiable benefit to the original question, which is analogous to that of the SpringBoot authors.
Those behind Spring IMO deliberately set-out to obfuscate, which reflects the obtuseness of their JavaDoc and API's (see SpringBatch API's as an example, if you think I am flaming) that makes one wonder the value of their open-source ethos.

My quest for figuring out SpringBoot continues.

**Update. 22-08-2022**

Read this (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.auto-configuration) and you will figure out for yourself what "opinionated" means.
There are over 140 Config classes that Springboot can use for this opinionated view, depending on what is on your classpath.
yes, on your classpath.
Finally and bizzarely, the annotation @SpringBootApplication *is* a configuration annotation as it includes it.
Go figure :=)

Comment: thanks for this, it really clarifies what I have been trying to figure out myself. So, please correct if I am wrong, in essence SpringBoot bundles a group of Spring annotations into "its own". For example, SpringBootApplication conveniently adds Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguratio and ComponentScan. If that is correct, it seems to me that what you are saying about having to memorise the world of SpringBoot annotations as it differs from the Spring ones, it is indeed some extra work.

Comment: Better late than never...sorry for the late reply. The short answer: YES. Who is going to remember which Springboot annotation wraps what? Unless you are coding in it on a daily basis. Even then, take a recent interview I failed, in which they wanted answers to the mix. of SpringBoot and bespoke transaction management they had created for their project...there must be hundreds of non-out-of-the-box combinations of usages out there...then, THEN try to navigate their release documentation (if any)...having put SpringBoot on your delivery pipeline path...OMG.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, Spring Boot is an opinionated instance of a Spring application.

Spring Boot is a rapid application development platform.  It uses various components of Spring, but has additional niceties like the ability to package your application as a runnable jar, which includes an embedded tomcat (or jetty) server.  Additionally, Spring Boot contains a LOT of auto-configuration for you (the opinionated part), where it will pick and choose what to create based on what classes/beans are available or missing.

I would echo their sentiment that if you are going to use Spring I can't think of any reasons to do it without Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot is opinionated view of Spring Framework projects.Let's analyse it through one program taken from Spring Boot Documentation.

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }
  }
```

It's a very basic REST API and you need to add `Spring-boot-starter-web` in your `POM.xml` for the same. Since you have added starter-web dependency, the annotation 
`@EnableAutoConfiguration` guesses that you want to develop a web application and sets up Spring accordingly.

Spring Boot auto-configuration attempts to automatically configure your Spring application based on the jar dependencies that you have added. For example, if `HSQLDB` is on your `classpath`, and you have not manually configured any database connection beans, then Spring Boot auto-configures an in-memory database.

It's opinionated like maven. Maven creates a project structure for you which it thinks is the general pattern of projects like it adds `src/main/java` folder or resource folder for you.

Spring boot helps in faster development. It has many starter projects that helps you get going quite faster. It also includes many non functional features like: embedded servers, security, metrics, health checks etc. In short, it makes, spring based application development easier with minimally invading code(Less configuration files, less no of annotations).

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-documentation-about

Answer (score 2):

- Spring eliminate boilerplate code.
- Spring-boot eliminates boilerplate configurations.
  [more](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-vs-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

- For *Spring Framework*, you need to configure your project using [`XML` configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-instantiation) or [`Java` configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java).

  But for *Spring Boot*, these are preconfigured according to *Spring* team's view for rapid development. That is why *Spring Boot* is said to be an *"opinionated view"* of *Spring Framework*. It follows *[Convention over Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)* design paradigm.

  *Note:* These configurations include view resolvers for MVC, transaction managers, way of locating container managed beans (Spring beans) and many more. And of course you can override any of these preconfigurations according to your need.
- *Spring Boot* supports embedded servlet containers like *Tomcat*, *Jetty* or *Undertow* to create standalone applications, which *Spring Framework* doesn't.