# How to implement basic Spring security (session management) for Single Page AngularJS application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, session, spring-mvc

I am currently building a single page AngularJS application which communicates via REST to a backend. The structure is as follow:

One Spring MVC WebApp project which contains all AngularJS pages and resources and all REST controllers.

A true backend which has services and repositories for backend communication, an API if you will. The REST calls will talk to these service (the second project is included as a dependency of the first one).

I have been thinking about this a lot but I can't seem to find anything that can help me. Basically I just need some security on this application. I'd like some kind of session management which is extremely simple:

- user logs in, session id is created and stored in JS/cookie on
  website
- when user would reload page/ come back later a check needs to be done to see if the session id is still valid
- no calls should reach the controllers if the session id is not valid

This is the general idea of basic session managament, what would be the easiest way to get this implemented in a Spring MVC webapp (no JSP's, just angular and REST controllers).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have 2 options for the rest API: stateful or stateless.

1st option: HTTP session authentication - the "classical" Spring Security authentication mechanism. If you plan to scale your application on multiple servers, you need to have a load balancer with sticky sessions so that each user stays on the same server (or use Spring Session with Redis).

2nd option: you have the choice of OAuth or token-based authentication.

OAuth2 is a stateless security mechanism, so you might prefer it if you want to scale your application across several machines. Spring Security provides an OAuth2 implementation. The biggest issue with OAuth2 is that requires to have several database tables in order to store its security tokens.

Token-based authentication, like OAuth2, is a stateless security mechanism, so it's another good option if you want to scale on several different servers. This authentication mechanism doesn't exist by default with Spring Security. It is easier to use and implement than OAuth2, as it does not require a persistence mechanism, so it works on all SQL and NoSQL options. This solution uses a custom token, which is a MD5 hash of your user name, the expiration date of the token, your password, and a secret key. This ensures that if someone steals your token, he should not be able to extract your username and password.

I recommend you to look into [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/security.html). It will generate a web app skeleton for you with REST API using Spring Boot and the front end using AngularJS. When generating the application skeleton it will ask you to choose between the 3 authentication mechanisms that I described above. You can reuse the code that JHipster will generate in your Spring MVC application.

Here is an example of TokenProvider generated by JHipster:

```
public class TokenProvider {

    private final String secretKey;
    private final int tokenValidity;

    public TokenProvider(String secretKey, int tokenValidity) {
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
        this.tokenValidity = tokenValidity;
    }

    public Token createToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        long expires = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000L * tokenValidity;
        String token = userDetails.getUsername() + ":" + expires + ":" + computeSignature(userDetails, expires);
        return new Token(token, expires);
    }

    public String computeSignature(UserDetails userDetails, long expires) {
        StringBuilder signatureBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        signatureBuilder.append(userDetails.getUsername()).append(":");
        signatureBuilder.append(expires).append(":");
        signatureBuilder.append(userDetails.getPassword()).append(":");
        signatureBuilder.append(secretKey);

        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No MD5 algorithm available!");
        }
        return new String(Hex.encode(digest.digest(signatureBuilder.toString().getBytes())));
    }

    public String getUserNameFromToken(String authToken) {
        if (null == authToken) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] parts = authToken.split(":");
        return parts[0];
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String authToken, UserDetails userDetails) {
        String[] parts = authToken.split(":");
        long expires = Long.parseLong(parts[1]);
        String signature = parts[2];
        String signatureToMatch = computeSignature(userDetails, expires);
        return expires >= System.currentTimeMillis() && signature.equals(signatureToMatch);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Inject
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**/*.{js,html}");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/protected/**").authenticated()
        .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());

    }

    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
    private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    }

    private XAuthTokenConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
      return new XAuthTokenConfigurer(userDetailsService, tokenProvider);
    }

    /**
     * This allows SpEL support in Spring Data JPA @Query definitions.
     *
     * See https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions
     */
    @Bean
    EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
        return new EvaluationContextExtensionSupport() {
            @Override
            public String getExtensionId() {
                return "security";
            }

            @Override
            public SecurityExpressionRoot getRootObject() {
                return new SecurityExpressionRoot(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()) {};
            }
        };
    }

}
```

And the respective AngularJS configuration:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('jhipsterApp')
    .factory('AuthServerProvider', function loginService($http, localStorageService, Base64) {
        return {
            login: function(credentials) {
                var data = "username=" + credentials.username + "&password="
                    + credentials.password;
                return $http.post('api/authenticate', data, {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "Accept": "application/json"
                    }
                }).success(function (response) {
                    localStorageService.set('token', response);
                    return response;
                });
            },
            logout: function() {
                //Stateless API : No server logout
                localStorageService.clearAll();
            },
            getToken: function () {
                return localStorageService.get('token');
            },
            hasValidToken: function () {
                var token = this.getToken();
                return token && token.expires && token.expires > new Date().getTime();
            }
        };
    });
```

authInterceptor:

```
.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $location, localStorageService) {
    return {
        // Add authorization token to headers
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            var token = localStorageService.get('token');

            if (token && token.expires && token.expires > new Date().getTime()) {
              config.headers['x-auth-token'] = token.token;
            }

            return config;
        }
    };
})
```

Add authInterceptor to $httpProvider:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

})
```

Hope this is helpful!

This video from [SpringDeveloper channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7yfnfvEUlXUIfm8rGLwZdA) may be useful too: [Great single page apps need great backends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJHZQyfOQYY). It talks about some best practices (including session management) and demos working code examples.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks a lot! I'm wondering though, as it seems now there is an explicit function in the factory for checking if there's a valid token, but how would I go about making the token check automatic (sending it in header with each request for example) and refuse requests that do not have a valid token?

Comment: @E.V.d.B. you add an interceptor to $httpProvider in the config block. I updated my answer with code example.

Comment: One more thing, how could I make some calls not need a token? Calls that every user is able to do (via website navigation)?

Comment: You configure this on the back end in Spring Security config. Use .permitAll() in case you use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter or the xml equivalent. Examples here https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/

Comment: Hmm okay then I have one more question, where/ how do I configure Spring Security? And where do I tell 'these REST url's are free to access and these need a token'? Because the http interceptor is on the client side, how can the spring security on the backend react to this?

Comment: @E.V.d.B. you configure it using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I updated my answer with an example. Do you use Spring Boot? If not you can check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080855/difference-between-spring-and-spring-boot/30081247#30081247

Comment: Didn't work on the project this weekend, will try out your solution today, will mark yours as the answer if I can get it to work ;)

Comment: Okay so I got an additional question. I managed to generate the skeleton with JHipster, if I'd like to extract just the token based security mechanism, do I just need the classes in {packagename}.security.xauth? These 4 classes, or do I need anything else for it to work?

Comment: You may also need to copy some configuration from SecurityConfiguration and everything it depends on. Also in your pom.xml add org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security. Do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: I don't use Spring boot and at this stage in the porject I'm afraid it's too much of a hassle to change everything to Spring boot, is this a problem you think? I waited with the security layer because it was never clear to me what was the best way and I thought it would be fairly easy to add later on. So I hope I can keep my project in the current state and add all this to it without changing too much of the current structure.

Comment: Then the best way for you I think is to gradually move configuration from SecurityConfiguration and from security package. After you start your app it may throw ClassNotFoundException, in this case you check in JHipster project where the class belongs to and add this as dependency to your project. Also you need to be careful with dependency compatibility. E.g. if you use Spring 3 then you should use Spring Security 3 etc.

Comment: I am using java based configurations so it shouldn't be a problem to transfer the needed configs, I'm gonna try some stuff out now and see if I can get it to work! Will keep this post updated!

Comment: I am trying to get it all to work but I'm getting Beans that aren't found. This might be a dumb question but do I need to provide my own implementation of UserDetailsService because I get errors saying there are no beans found for UserDetailsService...

Comment: I implemented a UserDetailsService myself and that error seems to be gone, but now I get an error that there's no bean for AuthenticationManager, do you know if that's something I need to implement myself also? I thought I read there's a default for that?

Comment: @E.V.d.B. when you use Spring Boot some of the beans are configured in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityAutoConfiguration.java and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.java You may need to copy some configuration from there. Also don't forget to move UserXAuthTokenController from JHipster.

Comment: After adding those two files it keeps saying No Bean found for AuthenticationManager. Does this mean I need to provide my own implementation just as I did with UserDetailsService?

Comment: Ok, major breakthrough! I removed these two security classes but added a dependency in my pom.xml to spring boot autocinfig and I added @EnableAutoConfiguration to my Spring config Java class, and now I don't get any `NoSuchBeanDefinition` errors! Authentication seems to work to so all is going well at the moment!

Comment: I marked your answer as the solution, thanks for your help! I almsot got it working, only the XAuthTokenFilter doesn't get reached so that's the only problem I am dealing with at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look from what has been done in JHipster https://jhipster.github.io/. You can even use it.

Jhipster is a spring boot + angular/angularjs generator. I often use it to inspire me and learn best practice.