# Why does this token based Spring Security filter not get called?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently working on a project in which I use Angular JS and Spring REST services. These last few days I've been trying to get some security into the system ([see my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126754/how-to-implement-basic-spring-security-session-management-for-single-page-angu)). I'm implementing token based security.

I got the basic stuff working, but the XAuthTokenFilter doesn't get called when requests are being done. I have no idea why, I think it's something very simple that I'm overlooking. The relevant classes:

XAuthTokenFilter (doFilter does **not** get called each request)

```
public class XAuthTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final static String XAUTH_TOKEN_HEADER_NAME = "x-auth-token";

    private UserDetailsService detailsService;

    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    public XAuthTokenFilter(UserDetailsService detailsService, TokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        this.detailsService = detailsService;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
            String authToken = httpServletRequest.getHeader(XAUTH_TOKEN_HEADER_NAME);
            if (StringUtils.hasText(authToken)) {
                String username = this.tokenProvider.getUserNameFromToken(authToken);
                UserDetails details = this.detailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                if (this.tokenProvider.validateToken(authToken, details)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(details, details.getPassword(), details.getAuthorities());
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

XAuthTokenConfigurer

```
public class XAuthTokenConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private UserDetailsService detailsService;

    public XAuthTokenConfigurer(UserDetailsService detailsService, TokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        this.detailsService = detailsService;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        XAuthTokenFilter customFilter = new XAuthTokenFilter(detailsService, tokenProvider);
        http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Inject
    private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Inject
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/scripts/**/*.{js,html}");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/protected/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/api/open/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());

    }

    private XAuthTokenConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new XAuthTokenConfigurer(userDetailsService, tokenProvider);
    }

    /**
     * This allows SpEL support in Spring Data JPA @Query definitions.
     *
     * See https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions
     */
    @Bean
    EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
        return new EvaluationContextExtensionSupport() {
            @Override
            public String getExtensionId() {
                return "security";
            }

            @Override
            public SecurityExpressionRoot getRootObject() {
                return new SecurityExpressionRoot(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()) {};
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I really have no clue why it doesn't get called, is there something wrong with my url `antMatcher()` statements?

My Context which might be good to include:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(AppContext.class) // The context from my backend which is included as a dependency
@ComponentScan("com.example.springsecuritytest")
public class RestContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        //RootContext
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RestContext.class);

        // Add RootContext using ContextLoaderListener
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Registering and mapping dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the request and the response that you get? Are you getting an unauthorized exception even though you have a valid token in the request?

Comment: No it doesn't get called, tried it with a breakpoint but it doesn't get reached. All requests succeed, even requests without the x-auth-token header (I try the request using the Postman browser plugin) so the token doesn't even get validated because the filter is never running apparently.

Comment: all url's (/api/open and /api/protected) all come through without being held up and without being run through the filter first.

Comment: So the security filter chain is not called at all? I have a similar setup using an custom token auth filter using xml config and I have the following in my web.xml: `<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>`

Comment: Yes it seems so, but this line would add it to the chain right? `http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);` It's really weird, although I never specify on which url the filter is mapped, should I do this anywhere? In the example I got this from (JHipster) the Filter is not annotated with @Filter and doesn't have URL mapping, do you think this is necessary?

Comment: The snippet I posted will have all requests pass through the spring security chain. Your config is only defining that inside the security filter chain the custom filter should be used at a specific position, but not that any requests should go through it.

Comment: Hmm okay I see, it's weird because I just 'recycled' the classes from the JHipster example and they're not explicitely annotated but should work. What would you suggest I try?

Comment: (I'm using Java based configs in the project FYI)

Comment: I would start by trying to configure a simple auth unit test with minimal configuration and test that requests are actually challenged for authentication, then add the custom filter. Check out this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security)

Comment: I have also just noticed that you are not calling `.httpBasic()` or `.formLogin()` in your config.

Comment: I am indeed not calling those, but I am not working with JSP's so I don't think they apply to the situation? EVERYTHING is based on REST communication from the Angular JS pages so do you think I still need httpBasic and formLogin?

Comment: These methods do a lot under the hood and are not specific to JSPs, but set up Spring Security for an authentication - Basic or a Form login. Since Spring does not support token auth out of the box, you are basically highjacking one of these two authentication methods. If I have some spare time I will try and reproduce my xml configuration in java and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this [git repo](https://github.com/kpentchev/spring-security-test). I have prepared a very basic setup that test security with and without a `tokenAuthenticationFilter`. The filter implementation is just a mock, setting a valid Authentication whenever the header is present, regardless of its value. Please also note the two application `WebApplicationInitializers`, which are `Servlet 3.0` conformant and are configuring the Servlet container programmatically (instead of web.xml).

Comment: Thanks for your effort and the example! But it seems to be a whole different way of working which I am not really looking for at the moment, I'd like to keep the configurations and such as it is now, which should work according to JHipster. It just seems like I missed one of the JHipster skeleton files or I'm overlooking something else.

Comment: I do explicitely want to thank you again for working out the example, it might certainly come in handy!!

Comment: I have tried to keep the configuration as minimal as possible. If you check out the `StatelessWebSecurityConfig`, you should note that I do only a few things differently to you: 1. secure all URIs; 2. use in-memory authorization vs a user details service and 3. place the `tokenAuthFilter` before `basicAuthFilter` and call `httpBasic()`

Comment: Hmm allright I am going to try and make mine more similar to yours to see if it fixes anything!

Comment: Just tried placing `.anyRequest().authenticated()` instead of the `antMatcher()` statements and adding `.and().httpBasic()` at the end, but all requests still go through without being caught or held up in any way :/

Comment: How are you testing it - Jetty/Tomcat? Have you created a `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` that loads your `SecurityConfig`?

Comment: I test it by running it on an embedded Tomcat and then doing some REST calls with the Postman browser plugin. I do have a webapp initializer but it doesn't load my SecurityConfig, I thought the @Configuration annotation would make sure it gets loaded? Should I add something to load the securityconfig? I have updated my question with my RestContext and Initializer.

Comment: I just put some breakpoints in the configuration files and they get reached and the XAuthTokenFilter actually gets added, I can inspect the http element and the list of filters actually contains the filter. So apparently the filter is not the problem, but it still doesn't get reached ...

Comment: I also noticed another weird thing. In the configuration the following statement is executed: `http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`. When I inspect the http element, there is no UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in the list of filters...

Comment: Add an additional initializer that extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` and in the constructor call `super(SecurityConfiguration.class);`

Comment: When I try that I get an error `SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
 at org.spr` apparently I can't have two initializers or something?

Comment: I have configured the git project to run with two `WebApplicationInitializer`. You can start it with mvn jetty:run. Also, make sure that you use a tomcat version greater than [7.0.15](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) in your project.

Comment: I pulled the project but how can I run it and see how it all works? I get 403 error on everything I try to access

Comment: I am no getting anywhere and this entire thing is driving me so crazy! I just need this damn mechanism to work (which it should out of the box according to JHipster), but it just won't work and I'm getting really frustrated D:

Comment: 403 is expected. Do a `curl http://localhost:8080 -H "X-AUTH-TOKEN: TEST" -H "application/json"`. As the token filter i have implemented is just a mock it will accept it and you should receive a response of "Hello world"!.

Comment: Okay I got everything to work suddenly and it was all thanks to your previous comments!! It turned out I indeed needed to explicitely include the SecurityConfiguration (before the securityFilterChain was not created, but now it is! I just added an Initializer AND added `SecurityConfiguration.class` to `protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()` in the WebAppInitializer! EVERYTHING is working now and I can't thank you enough!