# How can I keep a session between the frontend (angularjs) and the backend (java or c#)?

Tags: java, c#, angularjs, rest, authentication

I am developing a web application with angularjs in the frontend and java or c# for the backend, and I'll use REST communication.

My doubt is: How can I keep a session between the frontend and the backend? What tools show I use?

I have found something about OAuth and J2EE container authentication, but are those the only options I have?

Is there a library or something that does the job in transparent way, that 'hides' the complexity, that I don't need to manipulate cookies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I understood you, you'd need cookies/session/local storage... but what exactly do you want to achieve? Some mini example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement basic Spring security (session management) for Single Page AngularJS application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126754/how-to-implement-basic-spring-security-session-management-for-single-page-angu)

Answer (score 0):

Your session management and security implementation remains same as you would do for a non angular apps. If it's java I suggest using spring security. You have so many options for authentication, and you can protect your REST urls with simple configuration.